# Url.Action with RouteValueDictionary with Protocol

Tags: asp.net-mvc

been looking at this for a while, and feel like I am just being stupid want to get some more eyes on it..

I need to generate a full URL, (e.g. `http://www.domain.com/controller/action?a=1&b=2`), generally I just use [`Url.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.108).aspx) to do this with no problems by specifying the protocol:

```
var url = Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { a = 1, b = 2 }, "http");
```

I've started putting together a class that returns a `RouteValueDictionary` to make these anonymous objects disappear. However, I can't get it to work alongside the helper.

```
var x = Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new RouteValueDictionary(new { a = 1, b = 2 }), "http");
// "http://127.0.0.1/Controller/Action?Count=2&Keys=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BKeyCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D&Values=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BValueCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D",

var y = Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { a = 1, b = 2 }, "http");
// "http://127.0.0.1/Controller/Action?a=1&b=2"
```

Any pointers that lead to a facepalm greatly appreciated :)

**Update:**

It's probably best to clarify that in the above sample, I need to get the '`X`' variable working correctly, since the RouteValueDictionary is created elsewhere in code. Assume that the RouteValueDictionary is correct.

I just don't understand why this works with anonymous object, but the same object wrapped in the same object wrapped in a `RouteValueDictionary` makes the helper freak out.

Comment: How are you actually creating the RouteValueDictionary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The overload that you are using expects type "object" for the parameter where you are passing the `RouteValueDictionary`.  For some reason this is causing the issue, maybe something to do with .ToString()?  Use an overload that accepts a `RouteValueDictionary` and this should work.

To test this, add a hostName argument to select the overload shown below:

[image: Correct overload]

**EDIT**

You could use this extension in your project to add the overload that you require to Url.Action.  Internally it will resolve and add the hostName from the request.

```
public static string Action
    (this UrlHelper helper, string action, 
     string controller, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, string protocol)
{
     string hostName = helper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host;
     return helper.Action(action, controller, routeValues, protocol, hostName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this doesn't help me - as the anonymous object creation is still inline - this has been moved elsewhere to remove the duplication. I need to know why the 'X' variable in the question is wrong..

Comment: The anonymous object creation is inline in your x example?  Have you omitted the method call that you are using?

Comment: I've updated to clarify - the 'X' variable is using a RouteValueDictionary - assume that it's created elsewhere in the code. It's to just make an easy repro-case.

Comment: I need the protocol param to force the helper to generate the full URL. Otherwise, you just get the path (the URL is going into an email, so we need the whole thing).

Comment: In which case, can you add the hostName as another parameter? Will edit post

Comment: Ouch.. Hmm.. Not really since we'll end up having to get it from `Request` all the time, as environments change.. Damn this really has me scratching my head :(

Comment: Pleasure!  It's a shame it wasn't in the framework to begin with :(

Answer (score 15):

Interestingly, it looks like your specific example is matching a method signature that takes "object" as a property, rather than RouteValueDictionary. As such, it's just ToString()ing out the typename, rather than correctly serializing a RouteValueDictionary

```
 var x = Url.Action("Index", "Home", new RouteValueDictionary(new { a = 1, b = 2 }), "http", string.Empty);
```

Note **"string.Empty"** at the end.

That's enough to force the code to use a different overload, that accepts a RouteValueDictionary and as such, serializes correctly.

```
// http://localhost:55110/?a=1&b=2
```

Comment: The overload he is using is expecting object whereas most other overloads expect a RouteValueDictionary, see my answer.

Comment: Interestingly, you can also add a string.Empty as the host parameter to get the output you're looking for.

Comment: OK, this really have me confuzzled, the string.Empty works and is *slightly* better than having to hit `RequestContext` each time.

Comment: I just can't see a reason why my original code should cause the helper to freak out.

Comment: See my edit for an alternative to using string.Empty.  Strange how these overloads were created this way in the first place...

Comment: Dropped a pull request to add the missing overload in the queue for vNext: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/davidwhitney/aspnetwebstack/contribution/4236#!/tab/comments

Comment: In a little thread necromancy, pull request accepted, should be in ASP.NET V.NEXT: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/davidwhitney/aspnetwebstack/contribution/4236